# How to fix the error " message : "Missing \"data\" payload in the request " in strapi with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, strapi

I'm trying to send a post request in `vue.js` to create a new entry in `strapi`, but I'm getting the following error:

```json
message: 
Missing "data" payload in the request
```

P.S: I want to ensure that I can upload files too. I read that you must use `formData` for that, so I left it in the comments. I cannot seem to find a way on how to do that.

code:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

// Define refs for form fields
const fullName = ref('');
const emailAddress = ref('');
const phoneNumber = ref('');
const uploadPhoto = ref(null);
const location = ref('');
const merchantId = ref('');
const acuityLink = ref('');
const acuityId = ref('');
const acuityKey = ref('');

// Function to handle file input change
const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  uploadPhoto.value = event.target.files[0];
};

const submitForm = () => {
  // Create a FormData object to send the form data
//   const formData = new FormData();
//   formData.append('fullName', fullName.value);
//   formData.append('emailAddress', emailAddress.value);
//   formData.append('phoneNumber', phoneNumber.value);
//   formData.append('uploadPhoto', uploadPhoto.value);
//   formData.append('location', location.value);
//   formData.append('merchantId', merchantId.value);
//   formData.append('actuityLink', actuityLink.value);
//   formData.append('acuityId', acuityId.value);
//   formData.append('acuityKey', acuityKey.value);
//   console.log(fullName.value, uploadPhoto.value)
const strapi = {
        StoreName: fullName.value,
        StoreLocation: location.value,
        merchant_id: merchantId.value,
        ActuityLink: acuityLink.value,
        PhoneNumber: phoneNumber.value,
        ActuityKey: acuityKey.value,
        ActuityID: acuityId.value
}

  fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/barbers-stores', {
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ...',
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({data: strapi})
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
};

</script>

<template>
  <section class="container">
    <header>Registration Form</header>
    <form action="#" class="form">
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter full name" v-model="fullName" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address" v-model="emailAddress" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter phone number" v-model="phoneNumber" required />
      </div>
      <!-- New Fields -->
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Upload Photo</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="handleFileChange" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Location</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter location" v-model="location" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Merchant ID</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Merchant ID" v-model="merchantId" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Acuity Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Acuity Username" v-model="actuityLink" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Acuity ID</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Acuity ID" v-model="actuityId" required />
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <label>Acuity Key</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Acuity Key" v-model="actuityId" required />
      </div>
      <!-- End of New Fields -->
      <button @click.prevent="submitForm">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Files are being sent as `multipart-formdata`. To send your payload with file, you should use `new FormData()` Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you were getting the error when using new FormData.  I don't use view but here is an example in remix where I need to send an image and data.

```
export async function recommend(data, image) {

  const baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL
  const query = `/api/recommendations`;

  const url = baseUrl + query;

  const hasImage = image._name === "" ? false : true;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  if (hasImage) formData.append('files.image', image, image.name);
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })

  return response.json();
}
```

notice how I am appending my strapi data, I am not passing it individually like you were doing, I passing the whole object to 'data'.

```
  formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Hope this helps.